# Solr version field type

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm looking for a field type that supports comparing versions, meaning I will be able to run lucene query with range of versions and find only the relevant versions:

eg.
`sdkVersion: [3.0.0.0.1 TO 3.1.1.0]`

for example right now im forced to write something like this:
`sdkVersion:[2 TO 2.7.4.4] AND -sdkVersion:2.1?.*`
because 2.17 is actually smaller than 2.7

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a field type that will do what you are asking for.

I would approach this by always storing the full zero-padded version in the `sdkVersion` field, for example:

store `02.07.04.04` rather than `2.7.4.4` and store `02.17.00.00` rather than `2.17`

That way a query for `sdkVersion:[02.00.00.00 TO 02.07.04.04]` would do the proper filtering.